# How to create HTML test report with Ruby by using test-unit-runner-html

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, watir, testunit

I am working on Ruby with Selenium and Watir. I have implemented Test-Unit, now I have a need to implement HTML Test Report. I have gone through test-unit-runner-html, but not so lucky. Can somebody help me implementing test-unit-runner-html with my project. Suppose there is a suite containing different test cases and I have to implement on it. Here is the sample test suite:

```
require 'rubygems'
gem 'test-unit'
require 'test-unit'
require 'test/unit/runner/html'

class TestExample < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    puts "running the setup........."
    @number1 = 4
    @number2 = 2    
  end

  def test_add
    puts "asserting the add function: "
    numb1=@number1+@number2
    assert_equal(7, numb1 + 1, "added correctly")
  end

  def test_sub
    puts "asserting the subtract function"
    numb2=@number1-@number2 
    assert_equal(2, numb2 - 0, "subtracted correctly")
  end

  def teardown
    puts "running teardown......."
    @number = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: An exception occurred when I tried to use the test-unit-runner-html gem. The gem appears to be quite old (last updated in Jan 2012). It is quite possible that it is too out-of-date to work with the current version of test-unit.

Comment: What kind of exception occurred? As I am not facing such issue.. but implementing this with my project.

Comment: Is there any other way we can get HTML reports. I am asking in case you know.

Comment: I set the default test runner using `Test::Unit::AutoRunner.default_runner = 'html'`, which resulted in the exception `test-unit-runner-html-0.0.4/lib/test/unit/ui/html/testrunner.rb:29:in `exist?': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`. I do not know of any other HTML report runners. Is there a reason why you need it to be HTML?

Comment: Yes, there is requirement that I need only html test report of the tests I executed with marking passed/failed and with other relative data. I am stuck here, as over the internet there not so much information available about implementing HTML test report which can support test unit framework.